# CSS regex selector match one OR another condition?

Tags: css, regex

I'd like to match when `/(\sclassName|^className)/` is satisfied, but when selecting css. Hypothetically I would use like:

```css
[class(^|\s)='className'] {
  font-size: 5000px;
}
```

I've found this resource, which is very nice: [The Skinny on CSS Attribute Selectors](http://css-tricks.com/attribute-selectors/), but it doesn't mention this use case.

I just want to match "icon-" in the following 2 examples, but not the 3rd.

Here, this can be achieved with `[class^='icon-]`

```html
<div class='icon-something another-class'>
```

Here, this can be achieved with `[class~='icon-']`, but this does not match when 'icon-' is at the very beginning of the class string:

```
<div class='another-class icon-something'>
```

I do not want to match this, with -icon in the middle of a string. I believe `*=` will match this one, as will `|=` :

```html
<div class='another-icon-class another-class'>
```

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You'll need to use two separate selectors with the same rule. CSS selectors don't really support alternation.

```
[class^='icon-'], [class*=' icon-'] {
  /* ... */
}
```

```css
div {
  color: red;
}

[class^='icon-'], [class*=' icon-'] {
  color: green;
}
```

```html
<div class='icon-something another-class'>should match</div>
<div class='another-class icon-something'>should match</div>
<div class='another-icon-class another-class'>should not match</div>
```

Comment: Ah, that's a good idea to put a space in front of the * matcher. Alright, thanks for chiming in first with this solution, you get the check!

Answer (score 3):

You can use the following selectors to select any element whose class either starts with `"icon-"` or contains `" icon-"` (note the space at the start):

```
[class^="icon-"], [class*=" icon-"] { ... }
```

[**JSFiddle demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/EY6H2/).