# using regex for CSS class definition

Tags: css

I have a block of html something like this:

```
<div class="message-box01">...</div>
<div class="message-box02">...</div>
<div class="message-box03">...</div>
```

The 2-digit number appended to 'message-box' is breaking my css because the definition is like so:

```
.message-box ul li {
  background: #fff;
  color: #fff;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  border-radius: 15px;
  font-size: 25px;
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 15%;
  transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
}
```

So I'm wondering if there's a way to use a regex in the class definition, similar, I suppose, to what I'm seeing here: [another css related page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23963073/css-regex-selector-match-one-or-another-condition)

to use pseudo-code:

```
.message-box[\d*] {
    ...
}
```

Or something like that.

Alternatively, is something like this possible:

```
[id^='messages-box'] ul li {
    list-style-type: none;
    float: left;
}
```

Comment: And what is supposed to change in each class? Why do not use a global class and ids for each of the elements?

Comment: excellent question, and one that I've asked the original page developer about.  From what I can tell, those 2-digit ID's are somewhat extraneous but I can't be sure there's no relevance at all until I hear back from him.

Comment: Maybe you can set an ID more intuitive. For example: `box01`. Anyway, you will need to use `message-box01` to change the styles for this element specifically so I do not think there is a lot of problems to add an ID.

Answer (score 6):

If you have multiple classes with the same word you can use this

```
div[class^='message-box']{
  ...
}
```

> The above code applies to every div whose class starts with `message-box`.

Comment: brilliant, i've just found tis as well.  Would something like this work?


`[id^='messages-box'] ul li {
    list-style-type: none;
    float: left;
}`

Comment: Is there a way to extract that number from css class name, `padding-10` which will add padding of 10px, rather then writing multiple padding classes.