# jQuery classname with any number between

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I'm stuck about 4 hours searching and changing this small portion of code to be able to match my `classname`.

My page code is filled with `classnames` like this "option-274-82"

My jQuery function at some point try to match any div to show and must be something like this :

> "option-" + ANYNUMBER + "-" + ID

```
jQuery('.option-274-'+id+' dd').fadeIn();
```

The "274" it's just a control value and must be a regex expression, as I understand.

Many thanks for reading my question.

Comment: Can you post also your html ?

Comment: `$('.option-' + num + '-' + id).fadeIn()` ?

Comment: If you're trying to match the control value, something like this `$('[class*=" option-' + controlVal + '-"]').fadeIn();` Not really clear which number you're trying to match

Comment: the "274" number is a random number, unpredictable.

Comment: ok then how about `$('[class*=" option-"]').fadeIn();` It will match any class starting with `option-` Do you have access to this random value?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23963073/css-regex-selector-match-one-or-another-condition

Comment: No Ronnie, i can't control the number between. Just have the last one - $(this) element id. In my example i just have the "82".

Comment: `$("[class$='-" + id + "'],[class*='-" + id + " ']")`

Comment: Thanks Ronnie. Its working. Final code wasjQuery("[class$='-" + id + "'] dd,[class*='-" + id + " '] dd").fadeIn();

Comment: hoooray, I win!

Answer (score 4):

Using `filter()`, you can return all `div` matching the regex `^option-\d+-\d+$`.

```js
$('div')
    .filter(function() {
        return this.className.match(/^option-\d+-\d+$/);
    })
    .fadeIn(2000);
```

```css
.option-1-2, .option-1-a {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: #555;
  display:none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="option-1-2"></div>
<div class="option-1-a"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use attribute ends with selector

```
jQuery("[class$="+id+"] dd", document.querySelectorAll(".option"))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the selector "begin with" of jquery and can use filter to find the correct id

```
var element = $("[class^='option-'] ").filter(funtion(){
    return $(this).attr("class").match(new RegExp("option-\d*-" + id)) ;
})[0];
```

I hope help you