# can we combine two rule into single rule in css?

Tags: html, jquery, css, flexbox

I have two `senario` class started from `icn-` and in-betwen `icn-` .Both have same properties.can we add one selector or `regex` which work in both cases ?

```
 .f20 [class^="icn-"]:before,.f20 [class*=" icn-"]:before {
            font-family: 'icons' !important;
            speak: none;
            font-style: normal;
            font-weight: normal;
            font-variant: normal;
            text-transform: none;
            line-height: 1;
            -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
            -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale
        }
```

Comment: Any reason why `icn` is not a class? you can select based on multiple classes. Edit: for example if you make `icn-whatever` into two classes `icn` and `whatever`, then where you had `.icn-whatever` you can put `.icn.whatever` (notice no spaces). And that, would, of course, allow you to just select `.icn` separatedly if you needed.

Comment: This is related: https://stackoverflow.com/a/23963317/510788

Answer (score 0):

In your case you can write the following:

```
.f20 [class*="icn-"]:before {
   color: pink; /*whatever you want goes here*/
}
```

This selects any `icn-` class if it is either at the beginning or somewhere else. Note this also selects something like `this-icn-class` since it only checks for `icn-` and doesn't care what character is in front.